# IOThub mqtt support

Tags: mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I have created a test account to IOThub and pulled down the azure-iot-sdks git archive to test with.

I have added my connection string to both the iothub_client_sample_http and iothub_client_sample_mqtt .c files.

When I run the iothub_client_sample_http I see a couple of network packets sent and acked before I get a segmentation violation in pthread_mutex_lock called from PR_lock.  I will track this down and fix it.

More importantly, I want to use the MQTT protocol.  When I execute the iothub_client_sample_mqtt app I get a timeout in the connect code.  I have looked at the packets with wire shark and what I see is:

TCP 74  33226 > secure-mqtt [SYN] Seq=0 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=81898578 TSecr=0 WS=128

Then two more packets going out the same with retransmission.  I never see any reply packets.

Is there something I need to enable at the IOThub to allow using MQTT?

I actually want to use mosquitto in the product and I get the same scenario from my code.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to provide with more information. The official code samples have been tested on various platforms. For us to help you, you may need to show what steps you have taken to run the sample project.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use MQTT over WebSockets which uses 443 port instead of 8883.

See more details from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.  It turns out the company was filtering all packets to port 8883 and that was my issue.

MQTT has some particular advantages over other protocols to the hub.  As it becomes more popular IT organizations will need to change this type of thing.

Thanks again.

Comment: Any reason why you appear to be running 2 accounts?